# Кодировка в командной строке Windows

Tags: python, python-2.x

python 2.7 - как в Windows вывести составную строку если кодировка скрипта UTF-8?

**test1.py:**

```
# coding=UTF-8
import locale
import sys

print "preferred: ", locale.getpreferredencoding()
print "default: ", sys.getdefaultencoding()
print "stdout: ", sys.stdout.encoding
print "stdin: ", sys.stdin.encoding

print u"Путь "
print sys.argv[1]

print u"Путь %s" % sys.argv[1]
```

Вызов в командной строке Windows с кодировкой cp1251:

```
>cp1251
>python test1.py C:\Привет
preferred:  cp1251
default:  ascii
stdout:  cp1251
stdin:  cp1251
Путь
C:\Привет
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 13, in <module>
    print u"РџСѓС‚СЊ %s" % sys.argv[1]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Вызов в командной строке Windows с кодировкой cp65001:

```
>chcp 65001
>python test1.py C:\Привет
preferred:  cp1251
default:  ascii
stdout:  cp65001
stdin:  cp65001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    print u"Путь "
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
```

Comment: похожий вопросы: [Read Unicode characters from command-line arguments in Python 2.x on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/846850/4279) и [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При форматировании строки все части должны быть в одной кодировке. Переведите аргумент в unicode.

```
arg1 = sys.argv[1].decode('cp1251')
print arg1
print u"Путь %s" % arg1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало)

Comment: @Cumba более общий код: `sys.argv[1].decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`. Хотя и это может сломаться в общем случае. Правильный подход на Windows это использовать Unicode API как Python 3 это делает или самому руками вызвать -- [см. ссылки выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498577/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-windows#comment592990_498577)